# increment date with button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a StartDate Date Picker and an EndDate Date Picker. I am manually able to change the dates and the filter apply and work. I only do work in 3 month intervals. So I have a button which is `previous` and `next`. The issue I'm coming across is the interface doesn't change when I do press the buttons.

xaml side:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="StartDate" SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<DatePicker x:Name="EndDate" SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Button Content="Previous" Width="95" cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [Previous]" ></Button>
<Button Content="Next" Width="95" cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [Next]" ></Button>
```

MVVM side:

```
private DateTime _endDate;
public DateTime EndDate{ get {return _endDate;} set {_endDate = value;Filter();this.OnPropertyChanged("EndDate");}}
private DateTime _startDate;
public DateTime StartDate { get { return _startDate; } set { _startDate = value; Filter(); this.OnPropertyChanged("StartDate"); } }

public void Next()
{
    StartDate.AddMonths(3);
    EndDate.AddMonths(3);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("EndDate");
}

public void Previous()
{
    StartDate.AddMonths(-3);
    EndDate.AddMonths(-3);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("EndDate");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually set the date properties.  Calling `AddMonths` return a new `DateTime` object, rather than adding to the existing object.

```
public void Next()
{
    this.StartDate = StartDate.AddMonths(3);
    this.EndDate = EndDate.AddMonths(3);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("EndDate");
}

public void Previous()
{
    this.StartDate = StartDate.AddMonths(-3);
    this.EndDate = EndDate.AddMonths(-3);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("StartDate");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("EndDate");
}
```